# Как выровнять текст по центру картинки?

Tags: java, android

Рисую текст на картинке. Как этот текст разместить (по горизонтали) по центру?

```
Bitmap bitmap; //bitmap получаем из внешнего источника
Paint fontPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
fontPaint.setTextSize(20);
int bitmap1Width = bitmap.getWidth();
int bitmap1Height = bitmap.getHeight();
Bitmap overlayBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap1Width, bitmap1Height, bitmap.getConfig());
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(overlayBitmap);
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, new Matrix(), null);
canvas.drawText(text, 260, 100, fontPaint);
return overlayBitmap;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
...
fontPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
canvas.drawText(text, bitmap1Width / 2, 100, fontPaint);
...
```

Comment: Не выравнивает.. даже печатает как-то ближе к левому краю картинки, чем обычно.

Comment: думал "260" - это Вы уже нашли середину, обновил ответ, пробуйте :)

Comment: Все отлично работает) Благодарю!